# How to map names in a list to column elements?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column named "numbers" in which there are 100 values at random numbered from 1 to 5, and I have to create another column, "text" in which there will be the names corresponding to the value as defined for 1 to 5.
1: Surprise
2: Fear
3: Disgust
4: Happy
5: Sad

[image]
How to do this?

Comment: Hi you should give some more detail: What "columns" are these? In a CSV, dataframe? And what does your current code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1], [2], [3], [2], [5], [3], [1]])
df["text"] = df[0].map({1 : 'Surprise', 2 : 'Fear', 3 : 'Disgust', 4 : 'Happy', 5: 'Sad'})
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @pascscha